# Access wrapping element with `wrap()`

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery function `wrap()`, which returns the original object, not the wrapping object. Is there an easy way to access the wrapping object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `parent`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/parent)]</sup>* method:

```
$('#myElement').wrap('<div></div>').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give wrapping an element an id and reference it something like:

```
$('..........').wrap('<div id="mydiv" />');
```

Now you can reference the wrapper element using:

```
$('#mydiv')
```

Or you can simply use `parent()`

Answer (score 0):

After you wrap an element actually you are assigning a `parent` to it.

So, use `$('yourWrappedElement').parent()`